# Python 3: Iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I would've created a more specific title but I'm not sure how to formulate my question.

```
{
   "playerStatSummaries": [
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType": "AramUnranked5x5",
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalChampionKills": 2250,
            "totalAssists": 6199,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 114
         },
         "modifyDate": 1463737953000,
         "wins": 211
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType": "RankedSolo5x5",
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 928,
            "totalMinionKills": 15346,
            "totalChampionKills": 522,
            "totalAssists": 459,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 129
         },
         "losses": 35,
         "modifyDate": 1464273041000,
         "wins": 44
      },
      {
         "playerStatSummaryType": "URF",
         "aggregatedStats": {
            "totalNeutralMinionsKilled": 100,
            "totalMinionKills": 1379,
            "totalChampionKills": 138,
            "totalAssists": 125,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 25
         },
         "modifyDate": 1463946086000,
         "wins": 10
      }
   ],
   "summonerId": 85058811
}
```

I would like to iterate over this dictionary until I get to the "wins": 44 key/value pair. I need to dynamically reach it because the json file doesn't always have the same amount of entries so the index isn't always the same.

I know how to simply iterate over the keys:

```
for key in ranked_stats_json.keys():
    if key == "playerStatSummaries":
        print("reached")
```

but then I don't know how to iterate over the keys again, because there's another set of key/pair values within the "playerStatSummaries" block.

I also don't understand why the key/pair values here have multiple values, for example "playerStatSummaryType: "RankedSolo5x5, "aggregatedStats". I thought there could only be one value for every key.

So in short: how do I dynamically reach the "wins": 44 key/value pair in the "RankedSolo5x5" block if I don't know how many entries (blocks as I call them) there will be when I receive this file.

I'm sorry if this question sounds vague, it's because I'm quite confused how to solve this problem but do tell me if more information is required.

Comment: `playerStatSummaryType` only has one value. `aggregatedStats` has a colon after it which means that it is a seperate key, not another value of `playerStatSummaryType`

Comment: "I also don't understand why the key/pair values here have multiple values, for example "playerStatSummaryType: "RankedSolo5x5, "aggregatedStats".  --- **They dont.** The key is *playerStatSummaryType*, the value is *RankedSolo5x5*, the next key is *aggregatedStats*, the next value is a dictionary.

Comment: Do you only need the wins/44 pair or do you need all `wins`?

Comment: @Andy - just the wins/44 pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this syntax, a `{}` indicates a dictionary, while a `[]` indicates a list or array.

You have a `{` to start with, so your outer data item is a dictionary. The main key seems to be `"playerStatSummaries"` so let's access that directly:

```
data['playerStatSummaries']
```

Now, the playerStatSummaries is a list/array of items, so we'll have to either iterate over it, or use an index number into it. You have said that the number/order varies, so we'll iterate over the list.

```
stats = [summ for summ in data['playerStatSummaries']]
```

This creates a new list using a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that just contains the same elements as the list inside the data structure. But we can go further!

Each `summ` item is itself a dictionary, with keys like `'wins': 44` or `"playerStatSummaryType": "RankedSolo5x5"`. So we can use the `if clause` feature of our list comprehension to filter out the items you want:

```
stats = [summ for summ in data['playerStatSummaries'] if summ['wins'] == 44]
```

Or probably a better approach:

```
stats = [summ for summ in data['playerStatSummaries'] if summ['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'RankedSolo5x5']
```

Now you'll have a list of all the elements with 44 wins, or where the type is `RankedSolo5x5`.

Most likely, you'll have just one element. You can keep the list, and access it like this:

```
wins = stats[0]['wins']
```

Or you could just grab the 0'th element while you were doing the comprehension:

```
stat = [summ for summ in ... 'RankedSolo5x5'][0]
wins = stats['wins']
```

Comment: Thanks, you provided a working example with some good step by step explanations. Time for me to read up on list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for item in ranked_stats_json['playerStatSummaries']: ##This iterates the list
   if 'wins' in item and item['wins'] == 44: ##This checks your condition
      ##Do whatever here, or break or whatever you want  #Put your action here
```

Consider this example:

```
{ 'Dictvalue1':[
   {
   'List1key1': 'List1Value1,
   'list1key2': 'list1Value2
   }, 
   {
   'ListItem2key1': 'ListItem2Value1,
   'listItem2key2': 'listItem2Value2
   }
]}
```

Normally in a dictionary you reference by key and a list by position. It's the same when nested.

So if you wanted to reference ListItem2Value1 you'd put:

```
variable_holding_this_structure['Dictvalue1'][1]['listItem2key1']
```

Because the key "Dictvalue1" has a list as its value. In the list you want position 1 (second dictionary held in the list). In the dictionary held in position 1 of the list, you want the value associated with key 'listItem2key1'

This means you can iterate through any level of this per normal by referencing the level of nesting you are on properly or nesting your for loops

```
for item in variable['Dictvalue1'][1]:
   #do something

for item in variable:
   for subitem in item:
      for subsubtitem in subitem:
         #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the stats using a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
wins = [x['wins'] for x in data['playerStatSummaries']]
print(wins)
>>> [211, 44, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `if` condition on a list comprehension:

```
win_dict = [{'wins': x['wins']} for x in json_data['playerStatSummaries'] if x['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'RankedSolo5x5']
# [{'wins': 44}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
def get_wins(obj):
    wins = []
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for val in obj:
            if isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
                return_val = get_win(val)
                if return_val:
                   wins.extend(return_val)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for name, val in obj.items():
            if name == 'wins':
                wins.append(val)
            if isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
                return_val = get_win(val)
                if return_val:
                   wins.extend(return_val)
    return wins
```

Then, if you use `get_wins(ranked_stats_json)`, the output would be `[211, 44, 10]`.

The perk about this is, no matter what the content, if it has a `wins` key anywhere, you would get it.